# BXSlider multiple sliders on page - how to anchor link?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using BXSlider and have multiple slideshows on the one page. I'm trying to use anchor tags to allow me to link to the correct position on the page but it always ends up going to the bottom of the page (presumably because this is where the link goes to then the page re-positions itself once all the images have loaded).

I've tried putting the width and height of all the images in to see if this works but no change.

Any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="EN" lang="EN" dir="ltr">
<head>
<title>Brady Joiners | Gallery | Joinery Scotland</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layout.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png"  href="images/favicon.png">
<!-- bxSlider CSS file -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.bxslider.css" type="text/css" />
<!-- jQuery library (served from Google) -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.scrollTo-min.js"></script>



<!-- bxSlider Javascript file -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  adaptiveHeight: true,
  captions: false,
  mode:'fade',
  speed:1000,
});
});
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.bxslider2').bxSlider({
  minSlides: 3,
  maxSlides: 4,
  slideWidth: 256,
  slideMargin: 10
});
});
</script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.bxslider3').bxSlider({
  minSlides: 3,
  maxSlides: 4,
  slideWidth: 256,
  slideMargin: 10
});
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.bxslider4').bxSlider({
  adaptiveHeight: true,
  captions: false,
});
});
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.bxslider5').bxSlider({
  adaptiveHeight: true,
  captions: false,
  mode:'fade',
  speed:1000,
});
});
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.bxslider6').bxSlider({
  adaptiveHeight: true,
  captions: false,
  mode:'fade',
  speed:1000,
});
});
  </script>

</head>
<body id="top">

<!-- ####################################################################################################### -->
<?php include('templates/top.php'); ?>
<!-- ####################################################################################################### -->
<div class="wrapper col4">
  <div id="container" class="clear">
    <!-- ####################################################################################################### -->
   <?php include('templates/call-to-action.php'); ?>
    <!-- ####################################################################################################### -->
    <h1>Examples of Brady Joiners Work</h1>
    <p>Some examples of our work can be viewed below, for further details on any type of work contact us using either the numbers, email address of contact form below.</p>

    <h2 id="kitchens">Kitchens</h2>

    <div class="slider"><ul class="bxslider5" style="margin:0px; padding:0px">
  <li style="width:960px;height:637px"><img src="/images/gallery/traditional-kitchen.jpg" width="960" height="637" /></li>
    <li style="width:960px;height:637px"><img src="/images/gallery/contemporary-wood-kitchen.jpg" width="960" height="637"  /></li>
     <li style="width:960px;height:637px"><img src="/images/gallery/modern-wood-kitchen.jpg" width="960" height="637"  /></li>
     <li style="width:960px;height:637px"><img src="/images/gallery/modern-kitchens.jpg" width="960" height="640"  /></li>
</ul>
</div>
    <h2 id="garages">Garage Doors &amp; External Gates</h2>

    <div class="slider"><ul class="bxslider" style="margin:0px; padding:0px">
   <li style="width:960px;height:717px"><img src="/images/gallery/garage-doors.jpg" width="960" height="717" /></li>
   <li style="width:960px;height:717px"><img src="/images/gallery/garage-doors2.jpg" width="960" height="717"  /></li>
    <li style="width:960px;height:720px"><img src="/images/gallery/gates.jpg" width="960" height="720"  /></li>
</ul>
</div>

 <h2 id="lofts">Loft Conversions</h2>

    <div class="slider"><ul class="bxslider7" style="margin:0px; padding:0px ; text-align:center">
  <li style="height:720px"><img src="/images/gallery/loft/loft-conversion-2.jpg" height="720" /></li>
  <li style="height:720px"><img src="/images/gallery/loft/loft-conversion-3.jpg" height="720" /></li>
    <li style="height:720px">
      <div align="center"><img src="/images/gallery/loft/loft-conversion-4.jpg" height="720" /></div>
    </li>

     <li style="height:720px"><img src="/images/gallery/loft/loft-conversion-5.jpg" height="720" /></li>
  <li style="height:720px">
    <div align="center"><img src="/images/gallery/loft/loft-conversion-6.jpg" height="720" /></div>
  </li>
    <li style="height:720px"><img src="/images/gallery/loft/loft-conversion-7.jpg" height="720" /></li>

      <li style="height:720px"><img src="/images/gallery/loft/loft-conversion-8.jpg" height="720" /></li>
  <li style="height:720px"><img src="/images/gallery/loft/loft-conversion-9.jpg" height="720" /></li>
    <li style="height:720px"><img src="/images/gallery/loft/loft-conversion-10.jpg" height="720" /></li>

      <li style="height:720px">
        <div align="center"><img src="/images/gallery/loft/loft-conversion-11.jpg" height="720" /></div>
      </li>
 <li style="height:720px"><img src="/images/gallery/loft/loft-conversion-12.jpg" height="720" /></li>
    <li style="height:720px"><img src="/images/gallery/loft/loft-conversion-13.jpg" height="720" /></li>

     <li style="height:720px"><img src="/images/gallery/loft/loft-conversion-14.jpg" height="720" /></li>
  <li style="height:720px"><img src="/images/gallery/loft/loft-conversion-15.jpg" height="720" /></li>

</ul>
</div>


<h2 id="decking">Decking</h2>
 <div class="slider"><ul class="bxslider2">
 <li style="width:256px;height:207px"><img src="/images/gallery/asian-landscape.jpg" width="256" height="207" /></li>
  <li style="width:256px;height:191px"><img src="/images/gallery/decking-with-fence.jpg" width="256" height="191" /></li>
  <li style="width:256px;height:192px"><img src="/images/gallery/decking.jpg" width="256" height="192" /></li>
   <li style="width:256px;height:192px"><img src="/images/gallery/decking2.jpg" width="256" height="192" /></li>
   <li style="width:256px;height:192px"><img src="/images/gallery/decking3.jpg" width="256" height="192" /></li>
   <li style="width:256px;height:192px"><img src="/images/gallery/decking4.jpg" width="256" height="192" /></li>


</ul>
</div>

<h2 id="custom">Custom Work, Bespoke Furniture &amp; Walk-in Wardrobes</h2>
 <div class="slider"><ul class="bxslider3">

 <li style="width:257px;height:192px"><img src="/images/gallery/bespoke-bay-window.jpg" width="257" height="192" /></li>
 <li style="width:257px;height:192px"><img src="/images/gallery/bespoke-bay-window2.jpg" width="257" height="192" /></li>
 <li style="width:257px;height:191px"><img src="/images/gallery/walk-in-wardrobe.jpg" width="257" height="191" /></li> 
  <li style="width:257px;height:192px"><img src="/images/gallery/custom-desk.jpg" width="257" height="192" /></li>    
  <li style="width:257px;height:192px"><img src="/images/gallery/custom-desk2.jpg" width="257" height="192" /></li>   

</ul>
</div>
 <h2 id="cabins">External, Outdoors &amp; Cabins</h2>

    <div class="slider"><ul class="bxslider4">
  <li style="width:963px;height:716px"><img src="/images/gallery/cabin.jpg" width="963" height="716" /></li>
   </ul>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </div>
   <!-- <div class="gallery clear">
      <ul>
        <li class="first"><a href="images/gallery/garage-doors.jpg"><img src="images/gallery/garage-doors.jpg" alt="" width="572" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="images/demo/gallery/572x330.gif" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="Image 1"><img src="images/demo/gallery/174x150.gif" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="images/demo/gallery/572x330.gif" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="Image 2"><img src="images/demo/gallery/174x150.gif" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="images/demo/gallery/572x330.gif" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="Image 3"><img src="images/demo/gallery/174x150.gif" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="images/demo/gallery/572x330.gif" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="Image 4"><img src="images/demo/gallery/174x150.gif" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li class="first"><a href="images/demo/gallery/572x330.gif" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="Image 5"><img src="images/demo/gallery/174x150.gif" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="images/demo/gallery/572x330.gif" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="Image 6"><img src="images/demo/gallery/174x150.gif" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="images/demo/gallery/572x330.gif" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="Image 7"><img src="images/demo/gallery/174x150.gif" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="images/demo/gallery/572x330.gif" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="Image 8"><img src="images/demo/gallery/174x150.gif" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="images/demo/gallery/572x330.gif" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="Image 9"><img src="images/demo/gallery/174x150.gif" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li class="first"><a href="images/demo/gallery/572x330.gif" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="Image 10"><img src="images/demo/gallery/174x150.gif" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="images/demo/gallery/572x330.gif" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="Image 11"><img src="images/demo/gallery/174x150.gif" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="images/demo/gallery/572x330.gif" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="Image 12"><img src="images/demo/gallery/174x150.gif" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="images/demo/gallery/572x330.gif" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="Image 13"><img src="images/demo/gallery/174x150.gif" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="images/demo/gallery/572x330.gif" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="Image 14"><img src="images/demo/gallery/174x150.gif" alt="" /></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    -->
    <!-- ####################################################################################################### -->
   <!-- <div class="pagination">
      <ul>
        <li class="prev"><a href="#">&laquo; Previous</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        <li class="splitter">&hellip;</li>
        <li><a href="#">6</a></li>
        <li class="current">7</li>
        <li><a href="#">8</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">9</a></li>
        <li class="splitter">&hellip;</li>
        <li><a href="#">14</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">15</a></li>
        <li class="next"><a href="#">Next &raquo;</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>-->
    <!-- ####################################################################################################### -->
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- ####################################################################################################### -->
<?php include('templates/bottom.php'); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have any code for context? .. so we can see what your anchor tags *href* and code looks like

Comment: added. Adding height to li has seemed to work for some of the links but not all...

Comment: A codepen or jsfiddle example will help so we can see your code in action. You could just try to set the width and height on your .slider class and .bxslider3 DIV tags once. And then give your LI tags display block, and remove the width and height from all your LI tags, so they fill up the space of the slider, to me this looks more like a CSS issue.